# Django 500 server error using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, http-status-code-500

django website is working fine on localhost but when hosted on server using nginx and gunicorn, some APIs are throwing 500 server error. This problem is with some APIs and rest of the APIs are working well. Please help me what should I do?

Comment: Can you post the errors here?

Comment: you are saying hosting is ok then some of API call has issue means those view might be generating error.

Comment: There is very little we can do with that information. Please post the code of the API which fails along with full traceback and gunicorn configuration.